# dynamically create items in drop down list in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Small part of my html code :

```
<div class="text-center">

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Platforms <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id = "buttonsPlace">
            </ul>

        </div>
```

In my js file :

```
for (i = 0; i < platformList.length; i++) {
        var li =  $("<li/>" , { id : "plat"+i,class : "dropdown" text : platformList[i]  } )
        //var text = document.createTextNode(platformList[i]);
        //li.appendChild(text);
        //btn.data("platform", platformList[i] );
         $("#buttonsPlace").append(li);
        console.log("hiding");
        $("#plat" + i).hide();
    }
```

However the menu is appearing but the menu items are not. where am i going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
$(function() {
    var change = function( txt ) {
        $("#ID").append( '<li>' + txt + '</li>' );
    };
    change("this is the first change");
    change("this is the second change");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/Ahb8F/88/)

For Li Click

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function () {
   var id = this.id;
   //play with the id
});
```

Comment: yeah but how do i add the onclick function to these items in the dropdown list now?

Comment: even if i add the id like this <li id = "plat"+i> , how do i add click on function to these so that images are displayed on clicking them

Comment: what you want to do exactly?

Comment: i need to display images whenever i click on any of the items in the drop down menu. so for that i have attached IDs with all <li> items by doing <li id = "plat"+i> in the loop where i is variable. So that i can do $("#plat"+i).click() later on. but this isnt working. the drop down list is showing but the click function is not linked to the items in the menu

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){

        var countRows = $('ul.dropdown-menu li').size();
        $('.dropdown-menu').append('<li>Row '+countRows+'</li>');
        countRows++;
    });

});
```

Here is the jsfiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/ncgXK/

```
$('#drowdown-link1').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
});
```

Here is another jsfiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/ncgXK/4/

Comment: yeah but how do i add the onclick function to these items in the dropdown list now? even if i add the id like this <li id = "plat"+i> , how do i add click on function to these so that images are displayed on clicking them

Comment: Here you go [http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/ncgXK/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/ncgXK/3/)